# How to find my username and password for my proxy server?

Tags: windows-7, internet, proxy, authentication

I am trying to get data from URL using Python running on Windows 7. And I get a 404 error. Some more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350956/why-python-requests-get-a-404-error).

My interpretation of the problem is that the response comes from the proxy server and proxy responses this way because it does not get username and password from me.

So, my question is: How can I find my username and password (credentials) for the proxy. I tried to use my Windows credentials but they are not accepted. Apparently my browser have them because they can go through the proxy. So, how can I get them.

Comment: Try Nirsoft [IE PassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_password.html)

Comment: A browser won't know to prompt for/send credentials unless the proxy replies with a 403.  A 404 would just result in an error.  So it is unlikely that this is the cause of your issue.  It is more likely you are targetting the wrong port on the proxy server.